# Disadvantages to define a form bean with session scope in struts 1.x

Tags: session, struts, struts-1

What are the major disadvantages in using a form bean with session scope in struts 1.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `reset()` if your form contains attributes populated from checkboxes. You don't need that to request-scoped form beans.

You need to reset the form to its default values if you show a creation form for the second time, else the creation form will redisplay the data coming from the last created/updated object.

You can't have two browser tabs or frames using the same form, because they will walk on each other's toes.

Form beans should be in the request scope by default.

Comment: Thanks. I have a two-page form (the second form is dinamically generated from a json text). If I don't use a session form bean, how can I pass the bean to the second page?

Comment: Using a hidden field, or by storing the bean in the session under a UUID and passing the UUID as a hidden field.

Comment: in the first case, has the hidden field to represent a property of the second form bean?

Comment: Yes, since it's the second form bean that will be populated with this hidden field.

Comment: I've some problems to pass the bean as property of the second form bean. Could you look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585948/pass-a-bean-like-a-property-of-another-bean-struts-1-x

Answer (score 0):

Just try to work with both scopes and choose one preferred for yourself. But I should say there is small difference when you are working with persistent objects (and ORM tools like Hibernate), just because properties are persisted in database between requests.

1. Infamous checkboxes (and corresponding boolean properties). If you are working with persistent objects (editing boolean properties of some entity), you'll need extra code to *reset checkboxes anyways*. Scope doesn't matter because boolean property is persistent (isn't cleared automatically between requests).
2. When you are working with complex persistent objects (*hierarchies of objects*, mapped by Hibernate onto set of related database tables), often you'll just nest persistent object into form-bean and use nested properties, e.g. `<html:text property="purchase.client.name" />` (of course, you can create getters/setters in form-bean for each property of the entire hierarchy, but this is tedious and will complicate further development). For creation you'll just create new empty `purchase` object in form-bean, for edition you'll load existing `purchase` from database (request for edit will contain some identifier of object you want to change). Scope doesn't matter again.
3. About two browser tabs. More important and underestimated problem arises with usage of AJAX requests, especially when they are *not idempotent* and are *overlapped in time* (browser issues request for update 1, then request for update 2, while update 1 is *still processed* on server) - although it is very strange design (I mean overlapping update requests simultaneously in one session from one user). Yes, in that case you'll need to separate data in different requests. But moreover, your `action` (if we are talking about Struts 1) should be *thread-safe*, and your business logic should be ready to concurrent/conflicting updates (solve synchronization problems, lock objects, merge/override/reject updates etc.). If you are developing multi-user application, this may happen also when two different users want to change the same object simultaneously. Again, bean scope has little importance comparing to the whole problem.

As you can see, there is only one disadvantage with session-scoped form bean, and it arises only in relation to serious design flaw (overlapping update requests from one user).