# Pass a bean like a property of another bean (struts 1.x)

Tags: forms, javabeans, struts-1

I have two forms (and the corresponding form beans), one on page1.jsp and another on page2.jsp (this second form is dinamically created via json). The form1 is of `mypackage.MyActionForm1` type, while the form2 is of `mypackage.MyActionForm2` type. In the Action executed when the first form is submitted, I create a `MyActionForm2` and set the `MyActionForm1` form as its property:

```
MyActionForm2 secondBean = new MyActionForm2();
secondBean.setBeanProp(form1);
request.setAttribute("secondbean", secondBean);
```

In the jsp I succeed in accessing the properties of `form1`:

```
${secondbean.beanProp.prop1}
```

but how pass the first bean to the Action executed when the second form, `form2`, is submitted?

```
form2.getBeanProp().getProp1() // form2.getBeanProp() gives a NullPointerException
```

I wouldn't to use session scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a hidden field for every property of your `form2.getBeanProp()` bean, then obviously Struts won't be able to reconstruct this bean from thin air.

To be able to populate the property `prop1` of the bean returned by `actionForm.getBeanProp()`, you need a hidden field named `beanProp.prop1`. If you don't want to have the whole state of `beanProp` in your HTML form as hidden fields, then store this bean in session.

Comment: is the use of a session scope bean (form bean) bad practice (for example, in the case in which the multipage form allows to order a product)?